# How to find which database is an app using? And where can we find it

Tags: database

An app is stealing my contact details from phone, is there any way I can access its database and remove my contact list from there?

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can't**

Most of the databases require [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) in order to access it. Without a [key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(cryptography)), you can't read/ write data from it. Moreover, a key (for example, the client key) may only allow write access. If that database, which you've mentioned, was properly set up, it will be impossible to delete or even read your contact detail from it.

However, If you are just trying to find out what database it is using, you can

- [Decomplie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) the app: Find out how the app work and where your contact list was sent
- Use a [packet analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer): Monitor your network and see what (in your case, your contact list) is sent and where it is sent to

Comment: I decompiled it but I am not able to find it. Please help